# Create one object from a array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to create one object from array of objects with a a common key present in the objects.

Input

```
let data = [
    { code: "name", type: "text", value: "abc" },
    { code: "email", type: "email", value: "abc@abc.com" },
    { code: "username", type: "text", value: "xyz" },
  ];
```

Expected output

```
 {
    email: { code: "email" },
    name: { code: "name" },
    username: { code: "username" },
  }
```

I can iterate through the array using map function and manually create the object. But there should be an easy way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I struggled a bit to find out an elegant solution. But finally achieved

```js
let data = [
    { code: "name", type: "text", value: "abc" },
    { code: "email", type: "email", value: "abc@abc.com" },
    { code: "username", type: "text", value: "xyz" },
  ];
  
  
let result = data.reduce(
    (accumulatedObject, currentObject) =>
      Object.assign(accumulatedObject, {
        [currentObject.code]: {
          code: currentObject.code,
        },
      }),
    {}
  );
  console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

A forEach is simpler than map or reduce

```js
let data = [ { code: "name", type: "text", value: "abc" }, { code: "email", type: "email", value: "abc@abc.com" }, { code: "username", type: "text", value: "xyz" }, ];       
  
let result = {};
data.forEach(({code}) => result[code] = {code});
console.log(result);
```

If you must use reduce to save the result assignment, then you can do this which might even be possible to shorten further

```js
let data = [ { code: "name", type: "text", value: "abc" }, { code: "email", type: "email", value: "abc@abc.com" }, { code: "username", type: "text", value: "xyz" }, ]; 
  
let result = data.reduce((acc,{code}) => { acc[code] = {code}; return acc},{});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) and map the key/value pairs.

```js
let data = [{ code: "name", type: "text", value: "abc" }, { code: "email", type: "email", value: "abc@abc.com" }, { code: "username", type: "text", value: "xyz" }],
    result = Object.fromEntries(data.map(({ code }) => [code, { code }]));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I knew you could come up with something more unreadable ;)))

Comment: Can mine be shortened? `let result = data.reduce((acc,{code}) => { acc[code] = {code}; return acc},{});` I mean getting rid of the `{ return acc}` part